# v-select displays object Object

Tags: vuex, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm new to vuetify and I'm stuck on how to properly use v-select.  I'm pulling the select values from an API to a store called FormatTypes that looks like this:

```
[{"id":5,"formatlabel":"RDBMS Table or View"}
,{"id":6,"formatlabel":"Microsoft Access"}
....
,{"id":23,"formatlabel":"ArcGIS for Server image services"}]
```

my v-select:

```
<v-select font-weight-regular subtitle-1
          v-model=dataset.formattypeid
          :name="FormatTypes"
          :items="FormatTypes"
          :item-value="FormatTypes.id"
          :item-text="FormatTypes.formatlabel"
          :label="FormatTypeLbl"
          :outlined=true
           >
```

I've used the item-text/item-value props but I'm still getting the "object Object" in the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use binding and no need to link it back with the items in `item-value` and `item-text`

```
<v-select font-weight-regular subtitle-1
   v-model=dataset.formattypeid
   :name="FormatTypes"
   :items="FormatTypes"
   item-value="id" // No need of binding and no need of FormatTypes linking
   item-text="formatlabel" // No need of binding and no need of FormatTypes linking
   :label="FormatTypeLbl"
   :outlined=true
   >
```

Comment: After carefully reading your response, it resolved my issues - thank you very much.

Comment: Yea, sometimes it's very difficult to translate technical reasons to plain English. :P, Glad that I was able to help.