# Connect v-select with vuex: problem [object object]

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar, v-select

I am trying to create a dropdown (v-select/q-select (using quasar)), which allows me to select from an array in my vuex-storage and then eventually save the selected item (content of it) in a variable. Currently I have no problem to access the vuex-storage, but face the **problem**, that the v-select expects a string and not an object.

My code looks like the following.

```
// vuex storage:

const state = {
  savedsystems: 
     [
      id: "1",
      system: {...}
     ],
     [
      id: "2",
      system: {...}
     ]

 // example of the vuex storage out of my viewdevtools
 systemsconstant: Object
   savedsystems:Array[2]
     0:Object
       id:"first"
       system:Object
         7a73d702-fc28-4d15-a54c-2bb950f7a51c:Object
           name:"3"
           status:"defined"

         88519419-8a81-48f1-a5e6-5da77291b848:Object
           name:"5"
           status:"not defined"
     1:Object
       id:"second"
       system:Object
         7a73d702-fc28-4d15-a54c-2bb950f7a51c:Object
           name:"3"
           status:"not defined"

         88519419-8a81-48f1-a5e6-5da77291b848:Object
           name:"9"
           status:"defined"
}


// dropdown:

    <q-select 
      outlined 
      dense 
      emit-value
      :value="currentsystem"
      :options="savedsystems" 
      label="selectsystem" />


// computed to get systems from vuex:

computed: {
    savedsystems() {
      return this.$store.getters['systemsconstant/getsavedsystems'] 
    }
  },
```

I used the following example https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/aJQJyp as  inspiration and tried a couple of different setups stringifying resulting in nothing really.

If one would try to apply my case to a similar problem ([v-select displays object Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778132/v-select-displays-object-object)), the mentioned formatlabel would be an object instead of a string.

**Question:**
How can I modify the (with a getter) imported array of objects "savedsystems", so it can be used both as label to select it and furthermore then to connect it properly to the values, so I can save the selected as a variable.
Or can I change something in my v-select, e.g. varying what comes behind :options/options?

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: From your description the problem is not clear. I would need the code for select and also sample data  for savedsystems.

Comment: @KuldipShelke I changed it for possible later readers. Thank you Kuldip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the property `option-label`

```
    <div id="q-app">
      <div class="q-pa-md" style="max-width: 300px">
        <div class="q-gutter-md">
          <q-badge color="secondary" multi-line>
            Model: "{{ model }}"
          </q-badge>
    
          <q-select filled v-model="model" :options="options" label="Standard" option-label="description"></q-select>
          
          {{ model }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      model: null,
      options: [
        {
          label: 'Google',
          value: 'Google',
          description: 'Search engine',
          category: '1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Facebook',
          value: 'Facebook',
          description: 'Social media',
          category: '1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Twitter',
          value: 'Twitter',
          description: 'Quick updates',
          category: '2'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/bGpqJYx?editors=1010

Comment: awesome, thank you so much! That solved it. Now I'll head to write it in a new variable based on this.